# React-Native push to other route after a setTimeout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I would like to know if that possible to push to another route using a setTimeout function. I have a component who is a Loading page and what I want to do if after the loading phase is done I show a message text on the screen but after 1 seconds I push automatically to the other route.

I'm using react-native-router-flux.

```
const pushRoute = () => setTimeout(() => Actions.home(), 1000);

const PhotoPageOnSave = ({ photoState: { message, loading, error } }) => {
  if (loading) {
    return (
      <Container>
        <View style={styles.root}>
          <Spinner size="large" color="white" />
        </View>
      </Container>
    );
  }
  return (
    <Container>
      <View style={[styles.root, error ? { backgroundColor: '#C70018' } : null]}>
        <View>
          <Text style={styles.textStyle}>{message}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
      {() => pushRoute()}
    </Container>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do is for sure possible. What happens if you replace...

`{() => pushRoute()}`

with...

`{setTimeout(() => Actions.home(), 1000)}`

or

`{this.pushRoute}`

???

Comment: what's the problem? What are you seeing?

Comment: Nothing happen I stay on the page nothing I see my message but nothing else

Comment: Ok, how about moving the setTimeout function outside of the return(), between it and the render. In other words, just above the return keyword.

Comment: I should have noticed that earlier. Glad it worked :D

Answer (score 1):

I assume that this is part of a `render()` function?

You can do it, it just isn't usually done in the `render()` function.  Usually that sort of behavior is reserved for [`componentDidMount()`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) or [`componentWillReceiveProps()`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops)

Something like:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    if(!nextProps.loading){
        pushRoute();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok yes but if I want to show my message before pushing ? I mean I want the message to be show for 1 sec at least.

Comment: You've already found an answer you like at this point, but I'll let you know anyway.  `componentWillReceiveProps()` is called immediately before `render()` in the lifecycle.  I have a hard time believing that the render would take more than a few milliseconds.

Comment: Thank you your answer was good I just don't want to have the react component but more only the function. But thank for your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

you can write a promise in your pushRoute function

```
 pushRoute(dly) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve()
      }, dly);
    })

  }
```

and call this another function which must be async for example an onPress function

```
async onPress(){
var result = await = this.pushRoute(1000);
// and now you are free to call navigator.psuh here after 1000ms.

}
```